# JSonPath Test for top level value

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

I am using camel with JSonPath - the dependency places the version at 0.9.1

I am attempting to do a content based route based on a jsonpath

```
        <choice>
            <when>
                <jsonpath>$.(?(@.headerKey == 'reports'))</jsonpath>
                <to uri="direct:echoProcessorReports"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <to uri="direct:echo"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
```

The document that will be tested looks like this:

```
{"headerKey":"reports","data":[{"name":"reports0"},{"name":"reports1"},{"name":"reports2"},{"name":"reports3"},{"name":"reports4"}]}
```

I have been unable to nail down the syntax for this.  I tried various combinations using the jsonpath libraries directly:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathEngine;

/**
 * Created by mhampton on 1/29/15.
 */
public class CrapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String data = "{" +
                        "\"headerKey\":\"reports\"," +
                        "\"data\":" +
                            "[{\"name\":\"reports0\"},{\"name\":\"reports1\"},{\"name\":\"reports2\"},{\"name\":\"reports3\"},{\"name\":\"reports4\"}]}";

    JsonPath path = JsonPath.compile("$.");
    Object result = path.read(data); //net.minidev.json.JSONObject
    System.out.println(result);

    path = JsonPath.compile("$.headerKey");
    result = path.read(data);
    System.out.println(result);

    path = JsonPath.compile("$.headerKey(?@ == 'reports)");
    result = path.read(data);
    System.out.println(result);

    path = JsonPath.compile("$(?(@.headerKey == 'reports'))");
    result = path.read(data);
    System.out.println(result);

    path = JsonPath.compile("$.[*]");
    result = path.read(data);
    System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

And I have been able to extract the value ("$.headerKey"), but I cannot seem to get the filter expression to work for it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug, see also [JSONPath expression for checking string in Apache Camel XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816560/jsonpath-expression-for-checking-string-in-apache-camel-xml).

As a workaround, you may use:

```
<jsonpath>$..[?(@.headerKey == 'reports')]</jsonpath>
```

`[]` is the subscript operator (= array operator) and `..` stands for recursive descent. So, the expression means: return *all* elements (and not only the *top* element) with `headerKey` equals to `'reports'`.